Why is my shower faucet not stateless?
The faucet handle for my shower has one degree of freedom (rotating either clockwise or counter-clockwise) and does not allow controlling flow independently of temperature.  The handle turns clockwise from the 5 o'clock position to the 10 o'clock position.  Rotated to 5:00, the shower is off.  Rotated to 10:00, the water is very, very hot.  What is very confusing, however, is that the faucet does not seem to be stateless:

I rotate the handle clockwise to 10:00 to let the water get hot.
I rotate the handle counter-clockwise to 7:00 position.  The water is still very hot. (It doesn't seem noticeably colder at all.)
I continue rotating the handle counter-clockwise to about the 6:00 position.  The water becomes very cold.
I rotate the handle clockwise to about the 7:00 position.  The water is still very cold.
I continue rotating the handle clockwise to about the 9:00 position.  The water is still very cold.
I rotate the handle clockwise all the way to the 10:00 position.  The water becomes very hot.

We can't just rotate the handle to a specific position to consistently get a desired temperature.  Instead, we seem to have to repeatedly rotate the handle clockwise and counter-clockwise, and eventually we might get the water to become a comfortable warm temperature.  It always seems like a frustrating guessing game.
What is wrong with our shower faucet?
If it matters, I believe that the water pressure from the hot water line is higher than the from the cold water line based on my experience with a shower shut-off valve.

When water is heated in a tank the pressure does rise, but usually drops down again when hot water is used.  People and our overlords have made valves more complicated to prevent skin burns.  Sometimes they do not last as long.

So is this something that likely would be fixed by replacing the shower faucet cartridge?
